# Can you build a 3D isometric grid GUI in gradio.app?

Tags: python, isometric, gradio

I'm trying to demo [Free2CAD](https://geometry.cs.ucl.ac.uk/projects/2022/free2cad/) (for context), but I believe this question applies more generally: is it possible to create a 3d isometric grid drawing GUI with gradio.app?

I've noticed they have this api: [model3d](https://www.gradio.app/docs/model3d), but I'm not sure how to go about adapting it to create a 3d drawing interface? Is it possible? If so how simple would it be?

P.S. in case you suggest I just use the GUI demoed in the paper it isn't actually available & moreover I'm interested in gradio itself.